# Ok to use yepnope in multiple instances on the same page (like a pure async resource loader)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, modernizr, yepnope

Is it ok to use Yepnope like this, where I end up with multiple instances of Modernizr.load aka Yepnope on a given page by having a load instance for each widget? It could be 10-20 of them and some might load the same script.

I'm thinking it might be better to use another resource loader that is more buildt for dependencies etc, like RequireJS.

My problem with this is strange errors that only some times happens in IE8. Almost like it has something to do with the execution order of each Modernizr.load instance and the loading of scripts / callback.

```
<div id="myWidget-1">
    Widget that uses js loaded by yepnope
</div>

<script>
Modernizr.load({
    load: [
        'script1.js',
        'script2.js',
        'script3.js'
    ],
    complete: function () {

        ... do some stuff ... 

    }
});
</script>



<div id="myWidget-2">
    The same widget installed a second time, but with other settings. 
</div>

<script>
Modernizr.load({
    load: [
        'script1.js',
        'script2.js',
        'script3.js'
    ],
    complete: function () {

        ... do some stuff ... 

    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: YepNope documentation states "By popular demand, in yepnope 1.5+ we added the feature that scripts that have already been requested not be re-executed when they are requested a second time. This can be helpful when you are dealing with less complex serverside templating system and all you really care about is that all of your dependencies are available." Loading the same script file multiple times shouldn't result in it actually being executed multiple times based on that. Can you give specific details of the errors you are getting? Which version are you using? Is there a live example?